# Ansible privilege escalation with limited sudo

Tags: ansible, su

In my company we have limited root access, on this way on the sudoers.d :

```
user hostname =(root) PASSWD: /bin/su
```

I am trying to make ansible impersonate:

```
all:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: ssh
    ansible_become: true
    ansible_become_pass: 'password'
    become_flags: '/bin/su - root /bin/bash -c'

worker:
  hosts:
    hostname
```

But, every proof I have made, ends with this error:

```
hostname | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to hostname closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}
```

I have read about the privilege escalations and limited sudo:
[ansible privilege escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#id9)

but, on the host we are able to launch any sudo command on this way:

```
 sudo su -s /bin/sh -c "ls"
```

Is there any way to  make ansible use this method or is it impossible?

thank you

Comment: Just checking here: the only thing you can do is become root via `/bin/su`, and you need a password to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but not recommended because it requires root's password:

```
all:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: ssh
    ansible_become: true
    ansible_become_pass: 'root password'
    ansible_become_method: su
    become_flags: '-s /bin/bash'
```

In the client's file `/etc/sudoers.d/ansible` file is:

```
ansible hostname =(root) PASSWD: /bin/su
```

Running the following commands to show escalation works:

```
$ ansible -m shell -a "whoami" Client1 
Client1 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
root

$ ansible -m shell -a "who am i" Client1 
Client1 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
ansible  pts/0        2020-12-28 19:06 (192.168.122.36)
```